# How best to predict periodic data

Tags: predictive-models, fourier-transform

I have an event that occurs somewhat infrequently (for some data sets weekly, for some monthly, for some a few times a year, etc.).  For many (but not all) datasets, there is some regularity (the event occurs about every three months, for example.)  Each dataset is independent from the others.  I am considering applying a fourier transform to the data to try and predict future occurrences.  Is this a reasonable approach to prediction in this case?  Further, how do I go about determining the minimum number of samples necessary for a fourier transform to be meaningful for a data set?

Comment: The FT is not the best tool to look at event data. I'd rather look at the distribution of inter-event-intervals, and predict a new event to happen after an amount of time has passed since the last event, where this time is e.g. the mean of the observed distribution.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you could post an example data set.

Comment: This is not so a bad tool, if properly set up as a Power Spectral Density from the Fourier Transform and, under an ergodicity assumption, it indeed could behave in an interesting way, providing a distribution estimate on the frequency domain. If there is truly a periodicity trend on the data, the PSD or any Periodogram tool based on this concept would be good tools as start...

Comment: If you are needing for specific tools on this regard, just message me...